# Fedex. How To Login and Download Billing Onlive CSV File Programmaly?

Tags: fedex

I'm building a Fedex scraper with PHP. The Input are client Username and Password and i need download all billing online CSV in Manage -> View/Pay Bill -> Download Center

How i can login to Fedex and Download this programmaly ? I tried to use Curl but have no idea the form action and parameters.

Comment: Can you post some code?

Comment: Sorry, i'm asking the way to do this. How i can login to http://www.fedex.com/us/ programmaly ?

Comment: again u need to write a program having valid credentials to login the Fedex  site and then navigate to any page and then download the content.

Comment: @codefarm is there a specific API call you cannot get to work? They appear to have robust examples.

Comment: Thanks all. Yes i know that they have an API but some of the questions I have wouldn't be answered by it, I just need login to Fedex site and Download Billing. You can find in http://www.fedex.com/us/ Login form, they have many input hidden and the submit action they use a javascript function : CallLogin(). So i'm confused, i don't know how to login Fedex site. It would be great if anybody who have integrated it before

Comment: Hello! Did you find out any solution? I have same goal: getting invoices programmatically.

Answer (score 3):

FedEx Billing Online (FBO) is not open for web services. Current Webservices at fedex are:

**standard services(no certification required)**

-rate services

-service availability

-tracking and visibility

-fedex locator

**Advanced Services(require a certification process)**

-shipping services

-pickup services

-fedex express tag

-close services

-open shipping

-address validation

source:http://www.fedex.com/us/developer/

You can use a program like visualwebripper in order to simulate customer login into fedex.com at FBO and scrap the information.

First you need to log into the system and when you reach the main page of FBO you must find the information of current bills.

[image]

You must select the bills and press download them. This will move you to the second page-> search-download.

you must select each bill, select output format (xml, csv, excel, etc) and then press download.

finally the system will move to the download center and you must wait until the invoice link displays that its available for download.

finally you must download each file.

[image]

Two main considerations: first, its a difficult process even when you perform it manually, you have to check the bills. you have to select each file and then you must wait (or refresh) until the file displays the link.

honestly the best way to work with it is perform this process manual weekly or bi weekly - typical fedex billing cycle and use that information (eg: xml) importing it to your system.

in the past fedex offered EDI files but currently is not part of their offer.
brgds.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it, its not easy, the code will need constant maintenance because Fedex is altering their website ever so slightly every few months.  Is the purpose of this to do it for one account or hundreds of accounts?  The answer laid out by s_h is pretty much what you have to do.  I am not sure a PHP script is the right choice if you elect to do this on your own. FedEx's site can get very jammy from time to time pages don't load right away etc.

Keep in mind certain types of invoices will never have a csv download. If its an invoice with all smart post that invoice will only be visible as a pdf.  (even though fedex online will allow you start a download on a csv ---that notably will never actually download and become available. It may error out with the phrase "No Data")  You really also need a dbase to manage  what you have and have not downloaded etc.   You will have programming differences for customers who are credit card based versus invoice based, you have a multitude of permutations to contend with.  Sadly the API do not offer the ability to download invoices programatically.  This is definitely a web scraping type of deal.  If you google "small parcel auditors" you might be able to find a firm that will do the download for your company provided they are able to audit it for billing errors etc.  Thats one possible approach unless you're looking to get into this as a business or something.

Comment: This is exactly what I was doing for a client of my own, but the maintenance was pretty easy until about a week ago. Every time I refresh the page all the ID's are different now so I can't select things by ID. Additionally, I tried using paths without ID's, but the markup changes so much with each refresh that I couldn't use that either. Super frustrating, not even sure what to do next on this one.